# Remove xmlns attribute from elements when generating XML with LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a problem about generating `sitemap.xml`

My creator code is like this:

```
XNamespace xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
XNamespace schemaLocation = XNamespace.Get("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd");

XElement urlset = new XElement(xmlns+"urlset",
                  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
                  new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation));       

urlset.Add(new XElement("url"));
```

This code generates the xml file but the generated `sitemap.xml` url elements include an `xmlns=""` attribute.

```
<urlset xmlns="..." ><url xmlns=""/> </urlset>
```

All of the `<url>` element include that `xmlns = ""` attribute.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the Url?

Comment: If you are adding your Url nodes as such `urlset.Add ( new XElement ( xmlns + "Url" ) );` then you won't get empty namespace attributes...or at least I don't

Comment: I edited that urlset.Add(new XElement("url"));

Comment: If url and urlset both belong to the same namespace you qualify urlset, `xmlns+"urlset"` but not url

Answer (score 0):

I think the [W3 Org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#NS) can summize namespaces better than I, you have qualified namespaces for all nodes and attributes above the 'url' node. When you add`urlset.Add(new XElement("url"));` how should it determine the namespace it is under?

I would recommend trying this out and see how it works for you:

```
static void Main ( string [] args )
{
    XNamespace xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
    XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    XNamespace schemaLocation = XNamespace.Get("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd");

    XElement urlset = new XElement(xmlns+"urlset",
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
               new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemaLocation));       

    urlset.Add(new XElement(xmlns+"url")); // NB> We are qualifying the node
    var s = urlset.ToString( );
    Console.ReadKey( );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the  elements were including that `xmlns = ""` attribute.This solved my problem

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  // Create Sitemap
  XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
  var sitemapXml = new XDocument(
      new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
      new XElement( xmlns + "urlset", new XAttribute("xmlns", xmlns),
          from url in pageUrls
          select
          new XElement(xmlns + "url",
              new XElement(xmlns + "loc",  url),
              new XElement(xmlns + "lastmod", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
              new XElement(xmlns + "changefreq", "daily"),
              new XElement(xmlns + "priority", "0.8")
          )
      )
  );
  return Content(sitemapXml.ToString(), "application/xml");
}
```

Result:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://sabricihan.com/</loc>
    <lastmod>2023-09-12</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://sabricihan.com/Home/Contact</loc>
    <lastmod>2023-09-12</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://sabricihan.com/Blog</loc>
    <lastmod>2023-09-12</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
XmlDocument stripDocumentNamespace(XmlDocument oldDom)
{
    XmlDocument newDom = new XmlDocument();
    newDom.LoadXml(Regex.Replace(oldDom.OuterXml,
         @"(xmlns:?[^=]*=[""][^""]*[""])", "",
         RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline));
    return newDom;
}
```

Comment: Can I please understand why regular expression is bad practice to process XML?

Thanks.

Comment: Very briefly, regular expressions match what are called "regular languages" in CS. XML is not a regular language (nor is HTML). Regular expressions can't match all XML.